# redshift libs for pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-redshift

I am facing the following error while running my pyspark program.

```
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$1(JDBCOptions.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$1$adapted(JDBCOptions.scala:102)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.(JDBCOptions.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.(JDBCOptions.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:32)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:355)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:225)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I imported the libs as mentioned across couple of blogs, but end up facing conflicts in other spark libs. Pl share any post / thread explaining this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found this link while searching for an answer, closest to what I was looking for. I was able to get past my error ...

[How to include redshift libs in pyspark without conflicts](https://bigdatagurus.wordpress.com/2021/07/27/include-aws-redshift-libraries-in-pyspark/)

Hope this helps for those looking out for similar errors.